# Sql – Insert value only in first empty cell of column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, null

I have a Mysql table with 100 rows, id is primary key. I have a column_A that has some cells that are not populated, only null values.
Now, I want an sql statement that will insert a value to the first empty cell. And if I ran the php script again, then it inserts into the next null cell etc.
Something like:

```
$sql = "update my_TABLE, only affect the first COLUMN_A,row_i that is null
```

set COLUMN_A,row_i=20";

example:

```
COLUMN_A

6
7
null
null
null
```

after running the script,

```
COLUMN_A

6
7
20
null
null
```

Comment: Solved by @Filipe Silva

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET column_a = 20
WHERE column_a IS NULL
LIMIT 1;
```

But you really should have some kind of order by to really get the row that you want, like the following example:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET column_a = 25
WHERE column_a IS NULL
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0057)</kbd>

Comment: I promise this will be my last question.
I also want to have an sql script that will print within PHP (echo) the values of ID and COLUMN B values corresponding to the first COLUMN A null value (ie ID= 3; COLUMN B= 11).
How do I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user3043277. You better write a new question for that, as i'm not very fluent in php, and this comment is unlikely to get much attention, so you might not find an answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the help in original question. I will try to frame it in a different way and ask later.

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table1
SET column_a = 20
WHERE column_a IS NULL
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Question is already answered, copying answer posted in previous posts do not help anyone.